# How to explicitely close session of the whole browser

Tags: asp.net, session

In my web application, I use an exit button which runs session.abandon to close the session and then close the browser.

It does not work with multi-tabs in IE. If I open my application in two tabs, I click on the exit button in one tab which abandons the session and close the tab. But the application in another tab can still work.

Is there any way to close the session for this application in all the tabs?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you've a misunderstood of server session.

Closing server's session means clearing session's id and associated data to requester client.

A session starts when a client access to your web, and ASP.NET assigns a session identifier to it, ensuring subsequent requests would have an isolated set of data for this identifier.

When you abandon the session, that identifier expires.

Finally, when you open a new tab, ASP.NET starts a new session.

An ASP.NET isn't like a Windows application. "The application" is always started (excepting when application pool is recycled, IIS is restarted or the application hasn't been accessed already).

So, right, you abandon an user session, but the other tab should be in another session (if you've authentication, it should authenticate in order to work with your application, and so on).

Comment: "Finally, when you open a new tab, ASP.NET starts a new session" depends on how you open the tab. IE will open a new window with the same session-cookies if you press CTRL-N or CTRL-T. Other browsers work the same.

Comment: Yeah, right! But if you abandoned such session, session cookies will be outdated, useless. The server will set new ones.

Comment: Thanks Both. So if I open the same application in several IE tabs, they will share one session. After I click on exit button in one tab to abandon the session, if I work on the other tabs or open it in a new tab, it will start a new session.